# Outliers for all columns, with Grouping in R

Tags: r, group-by

How can I get a list of outliers for each column, for each group, **if I want to group the data by a certain column?**

I don't want to delete them, I just want to have them as an output.

Answer (score 0):

After grouping the data by the column of interest, `summarise` the rest of the columns by applying the `boxplot.stats` function, extract the `out` component and `paste` it to a single string (or can also return as a `list` column)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(grpColumn) %>%
     summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ toString(boxplot.stats(.)$out))
```

Answer (score 0):

A reprex would be very helpful in devising a solution to your problem. The challenge here is that each column may not have the same number of outliers, but a data frame's columns must all be of the same length. I would recommend gathering all the target columns into key value pairs, and filtering the resulting data frame instead. This will return a data frame containing all outliers (IQR method) identified by key value pairs.

In the below example I create a data frame with 2 data columns and one grouping column.
The `v1` and `v2` columns are gathered into a key and value column before grouping by `v3`. Then the new `value` column is filtered for any outliers using .25 - IQR * 1.5 and .75 + IQR * 1.5

This results in a data frame with 3 columns : `v3`, `key` and `value`, where `v3` is the grouping column, `key` contains the original data frame's column names and `value` contains the outliers from the original dataset.

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- tibble(
  v1 = rnorm(1000), 
  v2 = rnorm(1000), 
  v3 = c(rep("group a", 500), rep("group b", 500))
)

df %>% 
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", -v3) %>% 
  group_by(v3) %>% 
  filter(
    value < (quantile(value, 0.25) - IQR(value, na.rm = TRUE) * 1.5) | 
    value > (quantile(value, 0.75) + IQR(value, na.rm = TRUE) * 1.5)
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   v4 [2]
   v4      key   value
   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
 1 group a v1     2.75
 2 group b v1     3.33
 3 group b v1    -2.78
 4 group b v1     3.09
 5 group a v3    -3.33
 6 group a v3     3.29
 7 group a v3    -2.77
 8 group a v3    -2.97
 9 group a v3     3.05
10 group b v3     2.70
11 group b v3    -2.81
12 group b v3    -2.77
13 group b v3    -3.13
14 group b v3     2.76
15 group b v3    -3.07
16 group b v3    -2.96
```

This will only work if all columns other than the grouping column are numeric. Any other types will cause this to fail because all columns are gathered into a single value column which must be of a single type.